# Android convert image from gallery into base64 result in OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, android, memory

I would like to load image from gallery and then convert it into base64.

This does not sound so difficult. So i dod it this way:

first of all open gallery and choose picture:

```
picteureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            private Uri imageUri;

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            }
        });
```

second onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


        }


    }
```

and for the end way i want to decode my `image` which is at `picutrePath`

```
                String b64;
                StringEntity se;
                String entityContents="";
                if (!picturePath.equals("")){
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
                    b64=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                }
```

Unfortunatly I get :

```
06-24 16:38:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(3538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 16:38:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(3538): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-24 16:38:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(3538):     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
```

Can anyone point me where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of articles talking about this, basically you will need to calculate the dimensions before trying to decode it into a `Bitmap` have a look at the `BitmapFactory` class. I have an alternative solution for you, since you are picking a picture from the gallery, you can can get the `Bitmap` in `activityForResult`, like this:

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

and you can start your `Intent` for getting the images like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();    
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest to change

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
//added lines
bm.recycle();
bm = null;   
//added lines 
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
b64=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

That way, you're not loading the Bitmap twice into your app's memory.